# Retrofit to consume APIs

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I just started using `Retrofit` to consume APIs. I am able to update a User's profile successfully but I can't pass in the information to a User Object:

`Interface` RetrofitService:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/profile/update")
    public void updateUser(
        @Field("user_id") String userId,
        @Field("user_token") String userToken,
        @Field("first_name") String firstName, 
        @Field("last_name") String lastName,
        Callback<JSONObject> callback);
}
```

`Activity` ProfileUpdate:

```
updateProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Build RestAdapter
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/")
                .build();

        //Create API service
        RetrofitService service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);

        //Invoke method
        service.updateUser(
                user.getUserId(),
                user.getUserToken(),
                mFirstName.getText().toString(),
                mLastName.getText().toString(),
                new Callback<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    // user remains null!
                    public void success(JSONObject jsonObject, Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileMe.this, "Profile Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("succes", "Success!");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.d("failure", "Failed");
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

The above code works and the user's profile is updated. However the `JSONObject` in the `onSuccess` remains null.

I've been using `Gson` until now and I would do something like this:

```
//update user with new information
User user = gson.fromJson(responseData,User.class);
```

How do I do this with `Retrofit`?

**EDIT**
Response from the server returns a `JSONObject`. I changed the code above to satisfy those requirements but I am still returned a null `JSONObject`

Comment: Your rest API method "/profile/update" returns a user object?

Comment: Ah....it returns a JSONObject. But I changed my code around a bit and my JSONObject response was empty too

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/profile/update")
    public void updateUser(
        @Field("user_id") String userId,
        @Field("user_token") String userToken,
        @Field("first_name") String firstName, 
        @Field("last_name") String lastName,
        Callback<User> callback);
}
```

You need to set in the callback what you are expecting to receive in the response. If the WS returns a User object you need to set that in the callback

Comment: Change your log level to full and past here the log. Just set this in your retrofit client
setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your rest has a Object as return (Json formatter).

You need change your code to this:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/profile/update")
    public void updateUser(
        @Field("user_id") String userId,
        @Field("user_token") String userToken,
        @Field("first_name") String firstName, 
        @Field("last_name") String lastName,
        Callback<User> callback);
}
```

> Retrofit uses Gson by default to convert HTTP bodies to and from JSON.
>   If you want to specify behavior that is different from Gson's defaults
>   (e.g. naming policies, date formats, custom types), provide a new Gson
>   instance with your desired behavior when building a RestAdapter. Refer
>   to the Gson documentation for more details on customization.

**Edited**

If your server returns something like this:

```
{
"user_id": "21q3123"
"user_token":"asd2334rter"
"first_name" : "User Test"
"last_name" : "user last name"
}
```

On your Android client you need to have something like this also

```
public class User {

String user_id;
String user_token;
String first_name;
String last_name;

//Getter and Setters

}
```

Retrofit by default use Gson to parser all requests.

See here a good example of Paser.com and Retrofit:

[Android-Retrofit-Example](https://github.com/andersonacs/Android-Retrofit-Example)

Comment: Are you saying to write `Callback<User> callback` in my interface while writing `new Callback<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(JSONObject jsonObject, Response response) {    }` in my Activity? --- or change every callback to a user?

Comment: The server returns a JSONObject, not a User

Comment: "Retrofit uses Gson by default to convert HTTP bodies to and from JSON", You just need change the callback to User.

Comment: When I used GSON I had my class extends serializable and added @SerializedName for every instance. I'll try deleting them

Comment: exactly, using retrofit you do not have to worry about the parser objects to unless u are manipulating structure of complex objects.